# $location.path() vs $location.hash() in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

if my present URL is : `xzy.com/#/home/new`

`$location.hash()` gives `home/new` and `$location.path` also gives `home/new`

1. What is the difference in the two?
2. If inside the controller of home/new I write `$location.hash("#/home/new")` or `$location.path("/home/new")` both do not reload the partial but if I do `location.href="#/home/new"`, it reloads the partial. Why is this?

Also, if inside the partial there is a `<a href="#/home/new">` that will also reload the partial.
Why doesn't setting the path/hash reload the partial?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two parts to the route.

The first "hash" is really there just for browser compatibility and won't show if you are in HTML5 mode.

For example, given this URL:

```
http://localhost/spa.htm
```

If you set:

```
$location.path('/myPath');
```

you will get:

```
http://localhost/spa.htm#/myPath
```

In this case, the "hash" is just for the browser to hold the URL, the method is path. Note also when you call path without a preceding / it is added, i.e. `'myPath'` becomes `'/myPath'`.

If you subsequently set:

```
$location.hash('myHash');
```

You will get:

```
http://localhost/spa.htm#/myPath#myHash
```

Finally, let's assume you did not set the path first, then you'll get:

```
http://locahost/spa.htm#/#myHash
```

If you are using HTML5 mode, the path is appended without the initial hash.

The first hash is used to append the route, the second is a reference to content on the page. For example, if you use the `$anchorScroll` service it will respond to what is placed in `$location.hash()` and not in `$location.path()`.

To summarize:

```
http://localhost/spa.htm#{path}#{hash}
```

Comment: Thanks .. can u please also explain the part 2 of my question about the reloading of the partial..

Comment: it is perhaps because of the digest being calculated for such object, and giving the same result, and then doing nothing.

Comment: There is no need to reload the road if it hasn't changed. If you want to reload everything, you should implement a refresh method on your controller that does the desired action.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question this morning then Google led me here.
Inspired by other answers and some Googlings I've done, here is my result:

for example, given a browser url:

```
http://localhost:8080/test.html#!/testpath#testhash%20with%20someothers
```

in AngularJS ,

- `url` is

  > /testpath#testhash
- `path` is

  > /testpath

  in another word , from left to right ,`path` starts at the first character in url and ends at the `#` or `?` or the end of url.

  `path` always start with '/' .so ,if no `path` is specified ,the path is set as "`/`" rather than ""
- `hash` is

  > testhash%20with%20someothers

in another word ,`hash` starts at the next character of `#` in `url` and ends at the end of `url`

`location.href` is not implemented in AngularJS. when you say: `location.href="#"`,it behaves like clicking an `anchor` tag :

```
<a href="#">click</a>
```

when invoke the method `$location.path`,`$location.hash` as setters, they do change the browser url to match your demands.
And ,why you want AngularJS to **RELOAD** a page at all?  :)

Answer (score -2):

The reason for the second part of your question, why it is not redirecting might be:

You might need to update the binding, with $scope.$apply , this is required when you are using the code other than angular like native javascript, jquery code

for example:

```js
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $location.path("#/home/new");  
})
```